# DNS Lookup failing... but only for local records when queried from Windows on WiFi

Tags: networking, router, dns

Having a bizarre problem with DNS on my home network. Very short description: DNS Lookups that meet all of the following criteria are failing

- Target record is directly on the DNS server (i.e. there's no upstream request)
- Client is a Windows machine
- Client is on WiFi

Basic network description: Home cable broadband connection. Router is supplied by ISP, but I'm running a pihole instance that acts as both DHCP and DNS Server. On the pihole, I have a couple of local DNS records set up for convenience e.g. "storage" points to my NAS, "nginx" points to my webserver box, and "kodi" points to my Kodi media player. Simple enough, has been working fine for years.

Starting yesterday, for no reason I can see, lookups to these local DNS records started failing on my laptop (Windows 10 machine). `nslookup` would query the DNS server and just return "DNS request timed out". `nslookup` to external records that pihole has to go upstream for resolve fine. Rebooted DNS server, rebooted laptop, no change. Reboot router as well for good measure, nothing.

I have some Linux servers running on the network, so I run some tests from those. All DNS lookups resolve fine, both local and external. Check the pihole logs: as far as it's concerned, there's no difference between local lookups from the Linux servers or the Windows laptop - it thinks it's sending the same response to both. Ok, maybe it's specific to the laptop. Try from a different Windows laptop - same result as mine, local lookups fail, external lookups are fine.

But the thing that really throws me - when I connect my laptop to the router via Ethernet, everything works as it's supposed to. Local records resolve immediately to the correct record...

¯\*(ツ)*/¯

======================================

There is one unusual thing I can see that happened at approximately the same time as the issue started - a new, unknown device appeared on my network. It's definitely not connected by Ethernet, and WiFi is WPA2 with a strong password, so a crack seems unlikely. The only thing it appears to be doing is, once an hour or so, it makes a DNS lookup to "dcs-global.samknows.com".

The only explanation I can think of is that my ISP has pushed a firmware update that has done *something* to the router to enable this SamKnows device, and that has somehow had a knockon effect on the WiFi. As far as explanations go, it's not exactly robust, and may be a complete red herring, so I'm hoping someone on here has some idea of what might be going on.